# Why can't I use "$whoami" as a variable in "chown $whoami path"?

Tags: bash, variable

Why doesn't this work?

```
[my_user@archlinux ~]$ sudo chown -R ${whoami} /my_folder/path1/path2
chown: missing operand after ‘/my_folder/path1/path2’
Try 'chown --help' for more information.


[my_user@archlinux ~]$ sudo chown -R my_user /my_folder/path1/path2
[my_user@archlinux ~]$ ${whoami}
[my_user@archlinux ~]$ $whoami
```

But:

```
[my_user@archlinux ~]$ whoami
my_user
```

How to use the result of `whoami` in `sudo chown -R`?

Comment: a bit late, but perhaps someone is looking for chowing to the self user, wich is done with 'sudo chown $USER folder'

Answer (score 10):

The *variable* `$whoami` does not have a value.  You may give it a value with

```
whoami=$(whoami)
```

but in this case you may want to use the command substitution `$(whoami)` directly:

```
sudo chown -R "$(whoami)" /my_folder/path1/path2
```

A command substitution, `$(...)`, expands to *the output of the command within* (minus any trailing newline).

The variable `$LOGNAME` (and/or `$USER`) should have the same value as is returned by `whoami`, which means that you could also do

```
sudo chown -R "$LOGNAME" /my_folder/path1/path2
```